# Verilog: Check, if a signal is 100 ticks active?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have one input and one output. And I want to turn the output to 1, if the input was 100 ticks active (100 cycles).

```
module check_100(
   input wire clock,
   input wire reset,
   input wire in_a,
   output reg out_a);  

reg[10:0] counter;  

always @(posedge clock) begin
    counter <= counter + 1;
    if(in_a && (counter == 100)) begin
        out_a <= 1;
    end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly.
Is this a good way to check, whether a signal is 100 ticks/cycles active or not?

Thank you! :)

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code

Comment: Whops, sry. I wrote the code a little bit fast. But I'm only interested in the logic behind this check. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to increment your counter whenever the input is high (which you do) 
2) You need to reset your counter whenever the input is low (which you don't)  
3) You need to stop counting after counted to 100 (in case you want the output remain high). It will actually remain high in your case, but only because you are not doing the (2).

Answer (score 2):

You are checking whether the signal is active 100 cycles after start.

You really want to increment the counter only when the signal is active, and reset the counter when it becomes inactive.